# Selecting a NoteProperty in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

`Get-Website` returns a list of currently installed `Websites` and their `Bindings`.

However,

```
Get-Website | select Bindings
```

Returns the following:

```
bindings
--------
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement 
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
```

How do I get this right so I can export the data to CSV?

**Edited:**

If I type:

```
Get-Website | select -ExpandProperty bindings | select collection
```

I get the column just fine.
But then again I'd like to get also the other Properties like Name and Physical Path. How do I do that?

Comment: `Get-Website | select -expand Bindings` perhaps

Comment: Not quite...
Get-website | select -expand Bindings | select collection 
will get me that column but I wont be able to select the rest i.e name,physical path etc.

Comment: It was a guess. I dont have access to that cmdlet. It seems clear we will need to delve into this a little further. You should put a sample of what you are looking for specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what would work for you

```
Get-website | select Name,PhysicalPath, @{L="Bindings";E={$_.Bindings.Collection -join ";"}}
```

Using a [calculated expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) we break out the bindings and `-join` the array elements with a semicolon to allow it to be exported. This data should be easily exportable via `Export-CSV`

`Bindings` is an object and not just a string collection. Some have `ToString()` methods builtin that would take care of this for you but it does not appear that this one does so we need to do it manually.

Comment: Kudos my friend!
Worked like a charm.
And thanks for the "calculated expression" tip.

Comment: One small question though,
what's the difference between running this with and without "-join" ?

Comment: @user1571299 Doesnt really matter but we are using it to show a clear delimiter between bindings instead of a space. Could look better in export. Could also be useful depending on what you are using the export for.